# Applying background to ionic side menus

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm fooling around with ionic and angular.js and was wondering how to properly apply background styles to side menus. I do have a blured background image and content boxes hovering above the background image. My intention is when opening up the left or right side menu, the background remains fixed and only the content moves.

The left screenshot shows my result so far. The backgroundimage is attached to each content view of the menus, as otherwise setting it transparent the underlying content is reveiled. 
The right screenshot is a simple html mockup to illustrate the final result.

Does anyone have some suggestions?

[image: Illustration]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
    <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>

    <ion-side-menus class="sideMenus">

      <ion-side-menu-content class="custom">
        <h1>bdafs1</h1>   
      </ion-side-menu-content>

      <ion-side-menu side="left" class="custom">
        <h1>bdafs2</h1>
      </ion-side-menu>

    </ion-side-menus>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you'll need to set the background to the body and then make everything else transparent.

```
body        {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/hgzVvzN.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

.pane, .menu, .view, .list, .item       {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This approach not working on tabs template. while changing the page, the background also changes with the animation. Do you know how to do that in this case ?

Comment: @mmarques Could you create a new question with a codepen showing the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Andrew thanks for your anwser. I asked the question on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781956/ionic-how-to-keep-fixed-background-while-browsing-the-views